# Href Attribute Linked To Wrong Url in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I am working on PHP MVC Framework CodeIgniter, I have a base url set like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/portal_advseed';
```

I have changed my view folder outside of the application folder by changing the path in index.php at this line:

```
$view_folder = 'theme';
```

I have a header.php file located in theme folder which have some external files linked like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="theme/app-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
```

I have a controller named "Stock", It has method "view_stock". In view stock method I am loading the header view file like this:

```
$this->load->view("header");
```

Now when i run the url `http://localhost/portal_advseed/Stock/view_stock`in my browser, it does load the header file but the it does not load the external files.

I have checked in the view source option, The href attribute showing something like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="theme/app-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
```

When I click on the href link it goes there:

```
http://localhost/portal_advseed/Stock/theme/app-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png
```

And page show view not found error which is obvious, It should have actually goes to the link :

`http://localhost/portal_advseed/theme/app-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png`

So Why href is linked to wrong url? what is I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** I have also tried adding base_url and site_url but they are not working too. Instead after doing this href to linked to a url which shows the base url twice.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out the link are relative to the current page. You need to tell the links where they are on the site. You could use something like:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{$config['base_url']}theme/app-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
```